# Index creation on partitioned table is not completely offline in Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, nonclustered-index, online-operations

We have SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU10) (KB5001090) - 15.0.4123.1 (X64)
> Mar 22 2021 18:10:24    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
> Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0
>  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

where index creation is completely offline operation. So every `CREATE INDEX` statement render the table unavailable for reading/writing.
I partitioned one table and to my big surprise when I was creating all the nonclustered indexes on the same partition scheme this table was perfectly readable.
Is it a documented feature and where can I read about it?
All data modifications of this table was still blocked but there was no blocked readers at all.
This database has `RCSI` enabled if it could matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a documented feature and where can I read about it?

Yes. Below is the excerpt from the ONLINE = { ON | OFF } section of [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#online---on--off-) regarding OFF behavior. I added emphasis in bold.

> Table locks are applied for the duration of the index operation.
> An offline index operation that creates, rebuilds, or drops a
> clustered index, or rebuilds or drops a nonclustered index, acquires a
> Schema modification (Sch-M) lock on the table. This prevents all user
> access to the underlying table for the duration of the operation. **An
> offline index operation that creates a nonclustered index acquires a
> Shared (S) lock on the table. This prevents updates to the underlying
> table but allows read operations, such as SELECT statements.**